Creating hyperlink in popup that turns on different feature layer
I am writing (trying) Arcade code for ArcGIS Online Web Map that will create a hyperlink in a pop-up of one feature layer, which when clicked, will turn on another feature layer in the same map.
I have two layers:

Layer A (the layer with the pop-up)
Layer B (the layer to be turned on)

I'm trying to use ArcGIS Online's URL scheme for layer visibility through the URL parameters. Layer A and Layer B each have IDs from their AGOL web pages I have copied.
My code I put into an Expression is:
var layerBUrl = "https://<my-arcgis-online-url>/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=<your-webmap-id>&layers=<Layer-B-id>";
var hyperlinkText = "Turn on Layer B";
return "<a href='" + layerBUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + hyperlinkText + "</a>";

When I fill-in everything my code looks like this:
var layerBUrl = "https://arcgis.com/home/index.html/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=0b0c9d09e20a4c1fb6707a51c5e2bd51&layers=749872ef88fd4908984b11802ef7da58";
var hyperlinkText = "Turn on Layer B";
return "<a href='" + layerBUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + hyperlinkText + "</a>";

However, in the popup it doesn't work.
So I don't know where I went wrong.
I rewrote the code to make it more clear, but I get the same issue:
var orgUrl = "https://www.arcgis.com";

// Define the Web Map ID
var webMapId = "0b0c9d09e20a4c1fb6707a51c5e2bd51";

// Define the Layer B ID
var layerBId = "0b0c9d09e20a4c1fb6707a51c5e2bd51";

// Construct the URL with parameters to turn on Layer B
var layerBUrl = orgUrl + "/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=" + webMapId + "&layers=" + layerBId;

// Define the hyperlink text
var hyperlinkText = "Turn on Layer B";

// Return the HTML code for the hyperlink
return "<a href='" + layerBUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + hyperlinkText + "</a>";

I am able to build the URL, but the URL opens in a new tab. I just want to turn on a layer from another layer's pop-up.


So, your primary issue I think you will run into here is that AGOL doesn't seem to support any sort of attributes for the  tag that would allow you to control where the link opens. See https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-html.htm. The second issue would be that even if you accomplished opening the link the in the same tab, you would also need to read and subsequently pass the extent parameters of your current viewstate into whatever URL. Otherwise when the map reloads based on the URL, you will reload to the default extent.
